# Ajax post table every row first cell

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, html-table, http-post

Is it somehow possible to get table every row first cell input value and send it over ajax to PHP and it would send this information to mysql?

```
<table id="kogused">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>empty</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>empty</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

$('.addtodb').click(function(){
  $('#kogused tbody tr td.addr input').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert/insert_addr.php",
        data: "aadress="+ text,
        success: function(){
            alert('Õnnestus!');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });             
});
```

In this way - it adds two rows to DB but with the same value

Comment: Why not batch the POST, instead of firing a separate one per cell?

Comment: I'd probably flatten the table's data into JSON, and send it to the server in one go (unless the tables huge, then i'd batch the POSTs into reasonable chunks.)  It's pretty inefficient to send that small amount of data that many times to the server.

Comment: you're probably right because the table is usually at most 2-8 rows and every row not over 6 chars. I'm gonna try something with JSON. thanks

Comment: any time, i'd write it out for you, but i'd be answering a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it somehow possible to get table
>   every row first cell input value and
>   send it over ajax to php and it would
>   send this information to mysql?

To get every first cell, you would use the `:first` or `:nth-child` like this:

```
$('#kogused tbody tr td:first input')
```

Or

```
$('#kogused tbody tr td:nth-child(1n) input')
```